# How to prevent a Kivy Screen in Screen Manager From Loading

Tags: python, kivy

I am developing an application which uses Kivy as a framework. I am using ScreenManager to switch between groups of widgets and honestly it has gone very well as of now. My problem is that I am using OpenCV within an Image widget to disaply my webcam. When the python file runs it is clear that the widget is immediately loaded, from which my inference is that each screen loads at startup. I want to prevent my webcam from being on the entire time, and only have it enabled while this screen is loaded. If anyone has any ideas I would be eternally grateful

Python Code passing openCV data to an image widget:

```
class MaFF(Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MaFF, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.feed = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.face = cv2.CascadeClassifier('faceclassifier\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')
        self.label = ['Happy', 'Sad', 'Angry', 'Disgust', 'Fear', 'Surpise', 'Neutral']
        self.img_model = load_model("./faceclassifier/emotion.h5")
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 33.0)

    def update(self, *args):
        ret, frame = self.feed.read()
        height, width = frame.shape[:2]
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (0, height - 50), (200, height), (0, 0, 0), thickness=cv2.FILLED)
        faces = self.face.detectMultiScale(gray, minNeighbors=5, scaleFactor=1.1, minSize=(25, 25))

        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (100, 100, 100), 2)
            facex = frame[y:y + h, x:x + w]
            facex = cv2.cvtColor(facex, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            facex = cv2.resize(facex, (200, 200))
            facex = facex / 255
            facex = facex.reshape(200, 200, -1)
            facex = np.expand_dims(facex, axis=0)
            prepred_face = self.img_model.predict(facex)
            prediction = np.argmax(prepred_face, axis=1)
            lbl = None
            if prediction[0] == 0:
                lbl = 'Angry'
            if prediction[0] == 1:
                lbl = 'Happy'
            if prediction[0] == 2:
                lbl = 'Sad'
            if prediction[0] == 3:
                lbl = 'Surprised'
            cv2.putText(frame, lbl, (10, height - 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
        bufImg = cv2.flip(frame, 0).tobytes()
        img_txtur = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
        img_txtur.blit_buffer(bufImg, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        self.texture = img_txtur
```

KV Lang File Managing the screens and basic more basic widgets. The relevant one is CameraPage, which is reached through a button on MainMenu calling root.manager.current

```
#: import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition

WindowManager:
    transition: NoTransition()
    StartPage:
    CreateProfile:
    Login:
    MainMenu:
    Correct:
    Incorrect:
    CameraPage:
    QuestionPage:

<CameraPage>:
    name: "camerapage"
    MaFF:

    Button:
        size_hint: (1,.1)
        text: "Go Back"
        on_press:
            root.manager.current = "mainmenu"

<StartPage>:
    name: "landing"
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        Label:
            text: "Welcome To Smaff!\nLogin or Create a New Profile to Begin"
            halign: "center"

        Button:
            text: "Login"
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = "login"

        Button:
            text: "Create Profile"
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = "createprofile"

<Login>:
    name: "login"
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label:
            text: "Enter Login Details"
        TextInput:
            id: username
            text: "username"
            multiline: False
            write_tab: False
        TextInput:
            id: password
            text: "password"
            multiline: False
            write_tab: False
            on_text_validate:
                root.verify(username.text, password.text)
                root.manager.current = "mainmenu" if root.authenticated == True else "login"
        Button:
            text: "Login"
            on_release:
                root.verify(username.text, password.text)
                root.manager.current = "mainmenu" if root.authenticated == True else "login"
        Button:
            text: "Go Back"
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = "landing"

<CreateProfile>:
    name: "createprofile"
    Label:
        text: "This is the Create Profile Page"
    Button:
        text: "Go Back"
        on_release:
            root.manager.current = "landing"
<MainMenu>:
    name: "mainmenu"
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        Label:
            text: "Main Menu Here"
        Button:
            text: "Make a Funny Face"
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = "camerapage"
        Button:
            text: "Play"
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = "questionpage"
        Button:
            text: "Logout"
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = "landing"


<QuestionPage>:
    name: "questionpage"
    id: questionpage
    GridLayout:
        padding: "10dp"
        cols:1
        Label:
            id: "question"
            text: root.text
            text_size: self.size
            size_hint_y: .3

        Label:
            text: root.answer

        GridLayout:
            padding: "5dp"
            rows: 2
            cols: 2
            Button:
                text: "Happy"
                on_release:
                    root.manager.current = "correct" if self.text.lower() == root.answer else "Incorrect"
                    root.refresh()

            Button:
                text: "Surprised"
                on_release:
                    root.manager.current = "correct" if self.text.lower() == root.answer else "Incorrect"
                    root.refresh()
            Button:
                text: "Angry"
                on_release:
                    root.manager.current = "correct" if self.text.lower() == root.answer else "Incorrect"
                    root.refresh()
            Button:
                text: "Sad"
                on_release:
                    root.manager.current = "correct" if self.text.lower() == root.answer else "Incorrect"
                    root.refresh()
<Correct>:
    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
    name: "correct"
    GridLayout:
        cols:1

        Label:
            text: "Correct!!"
        Button:
            text: "Next Question"
            on_press:
#                root.refresh()
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = 'questionpage'
<Incorrect>:
    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
    name: "Incorrect"
    GridLayout:
        cols:1

        Label:
            text: "Wrong Answer, Try Again!"
        Button:
            text: "Next Question"
            on_press:
#                root.refresh()
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = 'questionpage'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move most (if not all) of the code in your `__init__()` method of `MaFF` class to a separate method that you call from an `on_enter()` method of your `CameraPage`. And you can add some code to stop the camera updates that can be called from an `on_leave()` method of the `CameraPage`.

See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen).

If you define a `loadcamera()` method in the `Maff` class, then something like:

```
<CameraPage>:
    name: "camerapage"
    on_enter: maff.loadcamera() 
    MaFF:
        id: maff
```

should work.

Comment: I'm kind of in a tight spot with this application, I got thrown into doing this and have never used Kivy before 2 or 3 weeks ago. I updated the Maff class like you suggested but I have to be missing something in the documentation on how to load this class into the screen.
`
<CameraPage>:
    name: "camerapage"
    on_enter:
        root.Maff.loadcamera()
`
is what I have with the kivy file. loadcamera() is where I moved the init code to, and i am declaring the variables in init by declaring them as none

Comment: Using `Maff` to access the `loadcamera()` method will not work. You need to access the actual instance of `Maff`, not the `Maff` class. Try adding an `id` to the `Maff` in the `CameraPage` rule in the `kv`. Something like `id: maff`, then use `on_enter: maff.loadcamera()`.

Comment: It works!!! Thank you so much! If i had at least 15 reputation points your answer would be upvoted

Comment: Just click the check mark to select it as the correct answer.

Comment: **sigh** that one shouldve been obvious to me, thanks man :)